# Angular js:ng-model is over writing the items in the ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-model

I have a strange problem with my ng-repeat array.

Currently, I am listing an array using `ng-repeat` and an edit button is placed to edit the particular item and save to the database.

But the problem is when the particular `item` in the text box is changed the `ng-repeat` items are also changed.

Here is the fiddle of my issue

https://plnkr.co/edit/D5NQitsRg7sCfZBE9IaB?p=preview

Change the value in textfield it will also affect the values in `ng-repeat`

Comment: @Sajeetharan check my fiddle you will get the issue

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you are assigning the reference of the variable that's why its changing. you have to copy the variable. below is working example:-

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
  
  $scope.items= [
       {id:1,name:'first'},{id:2,name:'second'}
    ];
    
    $scope.editItem = function(index){
    //edit
      $scope.edit = angular.copy($scope.items[index]);
      
    }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  
  <p ng-repeat="item in items">{{item.id+','+item.name}}
  
  <span ng-click="editItem($index)">Click to Edit {{item.name}} item</span>
  </p>
  
  
  <h2>Edit</h2>
   <input type="text" ng-model="edit.name" />
</div>
```

Comment: @Jabaa glad i could help :-)